# sIFR Mouse over styles and Scrolling Issues on Windows OS

Tags: sifr

I’m a windows OS user and use sifr3, I have some issues.

**I. MOUSE OVER STYLES:**

I have set color, hand pointer style, for mouse over.

```
firefox/safary:
```

After I scroll up/down a little by scroll bar in the browser, then I do mouse over on the embedded letter, but I don’t see the style I have set for mouse over.

**II. SCROLLIING:**

```
firefox/safary:
```

When I do mouse over on a letter I have embedded and scroll up/down by my mouse; then the scrolling is not working.

```
some other (google chrome/ IE7):
```

After click on the embedded letter, I cannot scroll by mouse too.

And I have tested with some sites that use sifr3, such as:

- http://dev.xiligroup.com/?p=235&cpage=1#comment-11543

  ```
  Note: It may have problem only in Windows OS.
  ```

Any one help please?

Best regards,

Rithy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to force the browser to update its message pump to the embedded flash UI element by specifying a hover style to 'embed' elements...
NOTE: the style has to force some sort of calculable change...
e.g.

```
embed:hover
{
    padding:1px;
}
```

Comment: Wow great answer to fix mouse over styles! But if use padding, then the flash will move. Now I use .sIFR-flash:hover{font-size: 10px; left: 0;} the flash is not move. But I still have problem with scrolling, because I didn't use embed elements, and because it's old version and its position is not good in my site. Could you help me with this?  

Thank you so so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This can be an issue if you have specified opaqueness or transparency on sIFR movies that are contained within floated content. Sadly this is a browser/Flash issue. Try removing the opaqueness or transparency and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ok, for the mouse over styles issue, I see it cause by transparency, but I really need the transparency. What could I do then?

Comment: I've tested, for sIFR 3-r278 doesn't have problem with scrolling, because the flash is in embedded structure <embed ..../>, but it still problem with mouse over styles. I really need help. It's urgent for me!

Comment: Doubt that it is due to using `<object>` but who knows. You could also try and get rid of the CSS floats, but I doubt that'd be possible. You sure you need transparency? Can't use a normal background color?

Comment: Its parent's using float left; Yes sure I need transparency; Cannot use background color.